# Android Google Maps SDK not loading for some users

Tags: android, google-maps, google-cloud-platform

I've published an app that uses the Google Maps SDK for Android.

I've heard some users (not everyone) are having troubles loading the map. This is what they are seeing https://paste.pics/FAUVC.

I can see in the console all of my requests so far have 2xx response codes. I'm not sure what is happening here. I believe permissions are granted and my API key should be.

Any ideas on what might be going on here? It's a bit hard to debug when I can't replicate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be due to the api key app restriction. (if you have one)

If you have an **app restriction** on your api key, make sure you have the right one into your api key settings. Apparently the app can has 3 SHA1 keys AFAIK, the **debug** one, the **release** one and the **debugTest** one.

Maybe you set the debug one (for exmaple) and you share the apk to some people with the release build variant. If not, try to delete the app restriction and add it again.

### Get the fingerprint

To get the app fingerprints, open **Android Studio** and go open `File->Settings->Experimental` and make sure you don't have the `Do not build Gradle task list during Gradle sync` box checked, after that, sync the project with Gradle Files.

Then, open the Gradle menu that you have on the top right side and navigate to `App Name->Tasks->Android->signinReport` and execute it. After that, the console will open with the fingerprints. The debug one should look like this:

```
Variant: debug
Config: debug
Store: /home/user/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: MD5 key
SHA1: SHA1 key <- this one
SHA-256: SHA-256 key
Valid until: Friday, September 22, 2051
```

Afterwards, copy the key and set it into your credential app restrictions and save it. Make sure that you put the correct **package name** of the app too.

Comment: This is kind of on the right path. So I contacted Google Support and they said I was using the wrong SHA1 key. I was using the debug build one when I needed to use the release one. To get the release one, I had to find it in my Google Console because I use App Signing from Google. Running `signingreport` only gives me the debug one.